# Attach external event to method

Tags: c#, reflection

I've been having a problem for a while and I just can't figure it out.

How can I attach an external event to a method or property?
What I mean is, how can I attach an event through reflection to a class so that whenever a method or property accessor is called an event will be raised (It should look something like this:

```
OnPropertyAccessing(object sender, PropertyInfo property, EventArgs e)
```

What I basically need is somehow to create an abstract class (or external using extensions) that (using reflection) handles all property or method calls for it's children who act as dummy classes and whom's only significance is the name of the property.

I expect this may be unclear, so, for example:

```
public class Father
{ ... }

public class Son1 : Father
{
    public string aaa {get; set;}
    public string bbb {get; set;}
}

public class Son2 : Father
{
    public DateTime ccc {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, nothing seems to mean anything in "Son1" and "Son2", this is because all of the actual "thinking" is done by "Father" who is alerted that a request has been made to  the property "aaa" of object "s" of type "Son1" and in turn decides what the property should return.

Obviously, I do not want to write something like this:

```
public class Father
{
    protected object pget(string propertyName)
    { ... }
    protected void pset(string propertyName, object value)
    { ...}
}

public class Son1 : Father
{
    public string aaa
    {
        get
        {
            return base.pget("aaa").toString();
        }
        set
        {
            base.pset("aaa", value);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I attach an external event to a method or property? What I mean is, how can I attach an event through reflection to a class so that whenever a method or property accessor is called an event will be raised

You can't, in general. That's just not something .NET supports out of the box.

You might want to look at an AOP framework such as [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), which supports this sort of thing.

(As an aside, even for demo code I would try to stick to .NET naming conventions.)